# Unable to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, system-installation

I have been struggling to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 11 in my Asus TUF A15 laptop.

Earlier I had Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 11 (dual-booted, both installed in the SSD) on my system, but then recently I needed to get some work done which was only possible through Ubuntu 18.04. I searched online and found that we can have 2 Ubuntu versions on a single system.  So I tried installing Ubuntu 18.04 on my HDD (since the SDD didn't have that much free space) from a USB. After installing, it showed that it had been installed correctly and that I needed to restart the system. After I restarted, in the grub boot loader, it showed Windows boot loader, Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 18.04 While windows and Ubuntu 20.04 loaded correctly, Ubuntu 18.04 was unable to boot and it showed some errors in the grub screen.

So I thought that maybe if I uninstalled both 20.04 and 18.04 versions and tried reinstalling only  Ubuntu 18.04, it may work. So after backing up my data from Ubuntu 20.04, I deleted the disk partitions, boot loader entries and the EFI entries of both these versions.

[Disk Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUGgi.png)

[EFI Entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrxXX.png)

However, now when I boot my system, Windows boots correctly, there are no Ubuntu entries in the UEFI settings also but in the "Boot from device" option it still shows Ubuntu even when no external USB is connected. If I click on this option, Windows loads.

[Boot From Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WUqs.jpg)

When I tried to install to install Ubuntu 18.04, I am unable to do so. It still installs correctly at first and after restarting, upon selecting Ubuntu in the grub boot loader, it doesn't boot and shows errors.

Comment: Why 18.04, often newer systems need the newest version of Ubuntu? kernel & drivers are more up to date. And does not boot does not help us in resolving an issue. Do you get grub menu? Then it boots, but a driver issue. Can you boot recovery mode from grub menu? Then a gui issue. Then what video card/chip does system have?

Comment: I do get a grub menu but after selecting Ubuntu it shows errors. Please have a look at my comment on Manu Mathur's answer

Comment: Also, I can go in recovery mode. Attaching the link for the errors here also: imgur.com/a/TH8q7li

Comment: I do not remember for sure, but did 18.04 have Safe Boot and the install of restricted drivers that included nVidia driver? You may just need recovery mode boot and terminal install of nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Install nVidia If you just want default version - recommended one
`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` If wrong driver installed, you must purge old drivers or will have major conflicts.

Comment: As you had advised, I started Ubuntu in recovery mode. I was unable to connect to the internet through the shell in recovery mode, so I clicked on resume (I thought it'll again show errors), but to my surprise, Ubuntu did boot (just without graphic drivers). I installed the software updates and also installed Nvidia drivers (nvidia-driver-510). But still, I'm getting the attached screen after selecting Ubuntu. One other thing which has also changed is that now when I click on Advanced Options for Ubuntu on the Grub screen, 4 options show up instead of 2. Image link: https://imgur.com/a/smgf3be

Comment: You normally have two kernels & two recovery modes. It keeps one older kernel just in case newest has issues. But does houseclean then even older kernels. What attached screen? Can you boot, or boot recovery mode? Recovery mode has with or without Internet.

Comment: Once powered on, I get a grub screen with Ubuntu, Windows, and other options. If I select Ubuntu, series of lines get printed on a black screen and it is stuck there (the imgur links I posted earlier). If I click on Advanced options and then Recovery mode, i get a screen with resume, root and some other options. I'm unable to connect to wifi through the shell. However, yesterday when I clicked on resume in the recovery mode, The normal Ubuntu GUI booted. I then did sudo apt update, installed drivers and softwares (through LAN). But now clicking on resume shows a black screen with a blinking _

Comment: Also, yesterday when Ubuntu booted after clicking on resume, and after I downloaded Nvidia driver (nvidia-driver-510), I checked through "prime select query" to check which GPU is enabled and it showed Nvidia. But when I checked in settings->details, it showed something else (can't remember what exactly did it show but it was neither nvidia nor the integrated intel gpu in my system).

Comment: Go back to yesterdays post with link on Black screen and options to fix it. If you have nouveau driver that is an open source but limited driver for nVidia cards/chips. Works ok with older nVidia, but generally better to use nVidia driver. Some more info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Answer (score 0):

My advice to you is this: Use "gparted" >> boot it through USB >> Delete all your HDD partitions (that belong to Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver) & Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS OS)).

Once done, restart your system into Windows & create a fresh bootable USB with either Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver) OR Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS OS (whichever version you want to use) using Rufus.

Restart your system again & boot from the newly created USB to install Ubuntu.
It should successfully run after it.

For setting up the Boot MGR [via Windows], type the following command in Windows cmd:

```
bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grub64.efi
```

Let know if this process works out for you.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I tried installing again in my HDD- Created a 150 GB partition, flashed the image on a USB, booted from USB, selected Install Ubuntu in the grub menu and then proceeded with the installation through the usual steps. However, still, the same errors persist. I have also attached some pictures of these errors: https://imgur.com/a/TH8q7li. I need to use some ROS packages which are compatible only with ROS Melodic (which in turn is compatible only with 18.04). I have Nvidia gtx 1650 GPU